# Request Location Update is returning the same coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

using mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates to request location update is returning the same coordinates. how can i solve it. it works properly with other devices below OS 6.0 but returns the same coordinates on a particular device of android OS 6.0

Update ** Also i noticed that when i installed Google Map on the device it started Fetching Correct coordinates. is that a coincidence ?

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class ActivateLocation extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MainActivity.this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> {
            if (!memoryLock) {
                memoryLock = true;
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                        checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    gPSTracker.mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                                if (location != null) {
                                    gPSTracker.location = location;
                                    if (gPSTracker.getLatitude() != 0) {
                                        isLocationReady = true;
                                        runOnUiThread(MainActivity.this::openLocation);
                                        if(notUpdatingLocation) {
                                            notUpdatingLocation = false;
                                            startLocationUpdates();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(e -> runOnUiThread(() -> new Handler().postDelayed(() ->
                                    new ActivateLocation().execute(contexts[0]), 30000)));
                }
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> new Handler().postDelayed(() -> new ActivateLocation().execute(contexts[0]), 30000));
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
            checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        gPSTracker.mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        if (locationResult == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                            if (location != null) {
                                gPSTracker.location = location;
                                if (gPSTracker.getLatitude() != 0) {
                                    isLocationReady = true;
                                    runOnUiThread(MainActivity.this::openLocation);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                null );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details so that people can reproduce your case, namely some code, and you haven't mentioned the model of the device that returns same coordinates

Comment: I have edited to show the code. i noticed that when i installed Google Map on the device it started Fetching Correct coordinates. is that a coincidence?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it is connected to GoogleMaps. It may be due to the fact that you check for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` but you only request COARSE permission, which is less accurate, try adding FINE to your `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`.